# Raspberry Pi - Go's `net/http` won't compile due to cross compilation

Tags: c, go, gcc, raspberry-pi

I'm having some trouble compiling a Go program on a Raspberry Pi. When I include `net/http`, I get the following compile error from `go build`.

```bash
admin@raspberrypi:~/repos/temperature-monitor $ go build
# runtime/cgo
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-marm'
```

This was solved by setting the Go env variable `CGO_ENABLED=0`.

My question is why this is the case, and if there is a different solution? I think this will only be a problem if a package requires CGo, and it would be nice to know how to get around this.

I tried using a recommended cross compiler `CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, but got a different compile error:

```bash
admin@raspberrypi:~/repos/temperature-monitor $ go build
# runtime/cgo
In file included from _cgo_export.c:3:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:25:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
   25 | #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I tried to fix this by installing `gcc-multilib`, but this isn't available for Raspberry Pi apparently.

Comment: "My question is why this is the case [?]" Because some stdlib code uses cgo if not turned off (for various reasons) "and if there is a different solution?" Yes, by having the appropriate C libraries and a working C toolchain ready (which you don't have, so : No).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where would I start in getting the C toolchain ready? Obviously I'm missing a library - but that can't be installed on my RPi. Am I using the wrong cross compiler? Is there another bit of configuration with the Go compiler that I'm missing?

Comment: If you do not have that library for your Raspberry than no toolchain or cross-compilation setting will make it appear magically so I do not understand your question. What exactly don't you like with the CGO_ENABLED=0 solution (which is common)?

Comment: And being common for a reason, namely it usually works? ;)

Comment: My issues is that it seems to me that there would be a reason why CGO_ENABLED=1 by default. In fact, as I carry on with my project, I need to use `go-sqlite` which requires CGO. Additionally, `gcc` is installed on my RPi - its the `-marm` argument that causes the initial issue, but that can't be modified in the C config.